# How can I enumerate through a folder to get all file names in an ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

How can I see all the images (`*.jpg` and `*.png`) in a folder, in my website?

All I can give is the location of the folder, but that is relative.

eg. `~/Images/Uploaded` or `/Images/Uploaded`.

cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon beats me to it but it may be worth mentioning the overload that takes a search pattern:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path), "*.png");
```

You'll need to mix the results for the 2 image types.

Comment: My bad. Downvoted by mistake. Can you update a lil bit so i can upvote it.. Currently its not allowing me to undo this -_-

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path));
```

In other words:

- Use [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get from the web path to the file system path
- Use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to find files on the file system

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to do BUT you need to first resolve the relative path to a "real one" using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` - for an example see http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath